# Swift : Replay AVAudioPlayer when song ends

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

Im trying to get the song to replay when the song ends but it doesn't seem to work. this is how I'm implementing it:

```
var music1 : AVAudioPlayer! = AVAudioPlayer()


func setUpMusic(){

    let music1Path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Lost", ofType:"mp3")


    let fileURL1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: music1Path!)

    do{

        music1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL1, fileTypeHint: nil)

    }

    catch{}

    music1.play()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameScene.replayFirstSong(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: music1)

}


func replayFirstSong(note: NSNotification){
    print("Inside Replay first song")
    music1.currentTime = 0
    music1.play()
}
```

Any idea how i can get the song to constantly play in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `numberOfLoops`:

Swift:

```
var numberOfLoops: Int
```

OBJECTIVE-C

```
@property NSInteger numberOfLoops
```

Setting it to -1 will loop indefinitely...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/numberOfLoops

Comment: GOT IT! Lets say i want it to be infinity but If i want it to stop when a user does something how can i get it to stop. Right now i do music1.stop() but that doesn't work, it just replays

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist: use music1.pause()  & for repeat player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.init(rawValue: 5)!

Comment: You would need an IBAction (like a button) or another function to call stop() - [read what it says about using it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/stop) with currentTime (which you might want to just get rid of)